# ExpandableList with button in detail

Tags: java, android

I have a Android expandableList, (group, child) and I want in every detail one button at the bottom?
After the user has clicked on the button, I want then display a popup (I think it's called a context menu) with Ok and cancel button.
When the user clicked on cancel the popup window has to be closed.
When the user clicked on ok, I want a new Activity where I can display the extra information about the goup he clicked on.

Also, how can I retrieve the correct data array from the expandableList

The data in the expandableList is made with a 2D string Array.

```
    arrChildElements = new String[user.getId.size() + 1][19];
    arrChildElements[0][0] = "Name : " + user.getName();
    arrChildElements[0][1] = "Street : "  + user.getStreet();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    for (int row = 1; row < user.getId().size() + 1; row++) {
            arrChildElements[row][0] = user.getBook.get(row -1).getID;
            arrChildElements[row][1] = user.getBook().get(row -1).getName();
            ...
            ...
            ...
    }
```

This is the layout I would like to have, The layout without the buttons works fine.

###
      ###
      ###
      ###
     [button]
  ####
      ###
      ###
      ###
      [button]
  ####
   ###
   ###
   ###
  [button]

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_item_layout, null);
    }
    TextView detail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleContentTextView);
    detail.setText(arrChildElements[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data for the child nodes always the same (Name, Street) or is it variable? If it's the same for all, the easiest way would be to have just one child with a layout containing all data (Name, Street) as well as the button you want.